# sed on a Bash string variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have a variable:

```
temp='Some text \n Some words \n'
```

I would like to delete some of those lines with sed:

```
sed -e '1d' $temp
```

I want to know if this is possible.

Comment: show the expected result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass your string as an argument, `sed` would interpret as a filename or a list of file names:

```
sed -e '1d' "$temp"
```

Of course, that's not what you want.

You need to use here string `<<<` instead:

```
temp=$'Some text\nSome words\nLast word'
sed '1d' <<< "$temp"
```

Output:

```
Some words
Last word
```

Comment: Notice the `\n` only is a linebreak here because of `$'\n'` quoting. With just `'\n'`, it would be a literal `\n`.

Comment: See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/6862601) as well.

Answer (score 0):

posix-compatible way to do this is:

```
temp="$(printf '%s\n' "$temp" | sed '1d')"
```

if you only need a bash-compatible solution see [codeforester's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42818359/5092659), as the  here string syntax is much better readable.